# ifstream equivalent of FILE *'s rewind method

Tags: c++, c

I've been tasked to update some C code to C++ and was curious, what is the equivalent method or implementation of C FILE *'s rewind method within ifstream?

Comment: I wouldn't automatically assume that iostream is an "upgrade". For many reasons, especially the statefulness of formatting controls, it's a downgrade, especially when mixed with threads.

Comment: I will take this into consideration.

Comment: A complete answer that works can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393583/how-to-read-same-file-twice-in-a-row

Answer (score 12):

That would be either [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) (sets the get-pointer) or [`seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) (sets the put pointer). In both cases, passing 0 as parameter results in the pointer being set to the beginning of the file.

Comment: You also need to clear the error flags (e.g. in case of EOF) via basic_istream<>::clear() as rewind does this.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
ifs.clear();
ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).