# How to read same file twice in a row

Tags: c++, file-io

I read through a file once to find the number of lines it contains then read through it again so I can store some data of each line in an array. Is there a better way to read through the file twice than closing and opening it again? Here is what I got but am afraid it's inefficient.

```
int numOfMappings = 0;
ifstream settingsFile("settings.txt");
string setting;
while(getline(settingsFile, setting))
{
    numOfMappings++;
}
char* mapping = new char[numOfMappings];
settingsFile.close();
cout << "numOfMappings: " << numOfMappings << endl;
settingsFile.open("settings.txt");
while(getline(settingsFile, setting))
{
    cout << "line: " << setting << endl;
}
```

Comment: SInce you're using c++, you can use a `vector` instead of an array:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/

Comment: Why not use a `vector<>` to store the information as you read it from the file the first time - the vector will automatically resize as it needs more memory.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp). Probably [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) actually.

Comment: Are all the lines/entries the same number of bits?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
settingsFile.clear();
settingsFile.seekg(0, settingsFile.beg);
```

Comment: Don't forget to reopen the file with settingsFile.open(filename);

Answer (score 5):

To rewind the file back to its beginning (e.g. to read it again) you can use `ifstream::seekg()` to change the position of the cursor and `ifstream::clear()` to reset all internal error flags (otherwise it will appear you are still at the end of the file).

Secondly, you might want to consider reading the file only once and storing what you need to know in a temporary `std::deque` or `std::list` while you parse the file. You can then construct an array (or  `std::vector`) from the temporary container, if you would need that specific container later.

Answer (score 4):

It's inefficient, use a `std::vector` and read through the file once only.

```
vector<string> settings;
ifstream settingsFile("settings.txt");
string setting;
while (getline(settingsFile, setting))
{
    settings.push_back(setting);
}
```

Comment: It may not be appropriate to use this method if file is too big and vector will not fit into memory

Comment: @mvp: that's true for an array as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
settingsFile.seekg(0, settingsFile.beg);
```

This will rewind file pointer to the very beginning, so you can read it again without closing and reopening.

Comment: This doesn't work. `while(getline(settingsFile, setting))` never happens.

Comment: @Celeritas that's because eofbit is still set. Call file.clear() before the loop.

Comment: @jrok thanks, under the hood is this better than just `.close()` and `.open()` the file again?

Comment: @Celeritas It certainly makes more sense than reopening :)